# Last item in a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to find the last item in a node, so I can specify whether to specify a comma or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="data.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<page generated="2011-04-19T19:22:21+00:00">
  <realm generated="2011-04-19T14:36:41-04:00" name="H-Bloodhoof">
    <item id="24033" name="Solid Star of Elune">
      <market>230000</market>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
      <reagentprice>39204</reagentprice>
    </item>
    <item id="5976" name="Guild Tabard">
      <market>60000</market>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <marketaverage>61162</marketaverage>
      <marketstddev>19735</marketstddev>
      <lastseen>2011-04-19T14:30:50-04:00</lastseen>
    </item>
    <item id="24036" name="Flashing Living Ruby">
      <market>1100000</market>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
      <reagentprice>99617</reagentprice>
    </item>
    <item id="23108" name="Timeless Shadow Draenite">
      <market>20000</market>
      <quantity>0</quantity>
      <marketaverage>20000</marketaverage>
      <marketstddev>0</marketstddev>
      <reagentprice>6500</reagentprice>
      <lastseen>2011-04-15T00:46:15-04:00</lastseen>
    </item>
  </realm>
</page>
```

Here's xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="realm">
    <xsl:apply-templates >
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">

    <xsl:param name="id" />

    <xsl:text>addonTable.marketdata[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id" /><xsl:text>] = {</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>["market"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="market" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>["quantity"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="quantity" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>["marketaverage"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="marketaverage" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>["marketstddev"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="marketstddev" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>["reagentprice"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="reagentprice" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

        <xsl:text>["lastseen"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="lastseen" />
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*)"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>

    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So right now it's checking for the last sibling of Item where I would like it do be the last element within the item.

```
addonTable.marketdata[24033] = {["market"] =230000["quantity"] =0["marketaverage"] =["marketstddev"] =["reagentprice"] =39204["lastseen"] =}

addonTable.marketdata[5976] = {["market"] =60000["quantity"] =1["marketaverage"] =61162["marketstddev"] =19735["reagentprice"] =["lastseen"] =2011-04-19T14:30:50-04:00}

addonTable.marketdata[24036] = {["market"] =1100000["quantity"] =0["marketaverage"] =["marketstddev"] =["reagentprice"] =99617["lastseen"] =}

addonTable.marketdata[23108] = {["market"] =20000,["quantity"] =0,["marketaverage"] =20000,["marketstddev"] =0,["reagentprice"] =6500,["lastseen"] =2011-04-15T00:46:15-04:00,}
```

It should look like this and it would be great if it doesn't print the empty values.

```
  addonTable.marketdata[24033] = {["market"] =230000,["quantity"] =0,["marketaverage"] =,["marketstddev"] =,["reagentprice"] =39204,["lastseen"] =}

  addonTable.marketdata[5976] = {["market"] =60000,["quantity"] =1,["marketaverage"] =61162,["marketstddev"] =19735,["reagentprice"] =,["lastseen"] =2011-04-19T14:30:50-04:00}

  addonTable.marketdata[24036] = {["market"] =1100000,["quantity"] =0,["marketaverage"] =,["marketstddev"] =,["reagentprice"] =99617,["lastseen"] =}

  addonTable.marketdata[23108] = {["market"] =20000,["quantity"] =0,["marketaverage"] =20000,["marketstddev"] =0,["reagentprice"] =6500,["lastseen"] =2011-04-15T00:46:15-04:00}
```

**Thanks for looking!**

Comment: The answer that you have accepted is definitely inferior to @Alejandro's answer. Please, consider accepting the best answer. Not to mention that you may actually learn something from it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="realm">
     <xsl:apply-templates >  
         <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">

     <xsl:param name="id" />

     <xsl:text>addonTable.marketdata[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id" /><xsl:text>] = {</xsl:text>

      <xsl:for-each select="*">                           
              <xsl:text>["</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>"] =</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>                                           
      </xsl:for-each>                                                     

     <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>                                                                                                                                               
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('addonTable.marketdata[',@id,'] = {')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>}&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item/*">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[&quot;',name(),'&quot;] = ',.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

`addonTable.marketdata[24033] = {["market"] = 230000,["quantity"] = 0,["reagentprice"] = 39204}`
`addonTable.marketdata[5976] = {["market"] = 60000,["quantity"] = 1,["marketaverage"] = 61162,["marketstddev"] = 19735,["lastseen"] = 2011-04-19T14:30:50-04:00}`
`addonTable.marketdata[24036] = {["market"] = 1100000,["quantity"] = 0,["reagentprice"] = 99617}`
`addonTable.marketdata[23108] = {["market"] = 20000,["quantity"] = 0,["marketaverage"] = 20000,["marketstddev"] = 0,["reagentprice"] = 6500,["lastseen"] = 2011-04-15T00:46:15-04:00}`

Comment: Many people write code that puts the comma "after every item except the last". Alejandro is advocating code that puts it "before every item except the first". I'd like to endorse that: testing whether the current item is the last may be inefficient unless you have a smart optimizer, and it may make your code non-streamable. Testing whether it's the first is much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a template for market|quantity|etc and move teh comma check into tha, it will also simplify what your are currently doing.